# when one sample size is less than 30 and the other is greater than 30

Tags: confidence-interval, mean, sample-size

I'm trying to solve for confidence interval for the difference in means and i was given two sample sizes, one less than 30 and the other greater. i dont know if this requires a t test or z test. which is appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot go wrong with a t-test. The Z-test is only an approximation for very large N's (or when the standard deviations are known, which is rarely the case).

Comment: For a confidence interval you need to invert using the appropriate pivotal quantity.  The normal/ Gaussian distribution test is not magically appropriate when the sample size exceeds 30.